Mistake in prolog code involving maths functions tasks
% Function for calculating the factorial

factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, F) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    factorial(N1, F1),
    F is N * F1.

% Function for calculating the approximate value of the function

approx_exp(X, N, Y) :-
    X1 is X - 1,
    fact_pow(X1, N, P),
    Y is P / N.

% Probability that the number

pow(_, 0, 1).
pow(X, N, Result) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    pow(X, N1, Result1),
    Result is Result1 * X.

% Function for calculating the Taylor series

expser(X, N, Result) :-
    expser(X, N, 0, Result).
expser(_, 0, Acc, Acc).
expser(X, N, Acc, Result) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    factor(N, Fact),
    pow(X, N, Power),
    Term is Power / Fact,
    NewAcc is Acc + Term,
    expser(X, N1, NewAcc, Result).

% Example of using

start_exp :-
    write('Enter the numer of group of N: '),
    read(N),
    write('Enter the value of the variable X: '),
    read(X),
    sum_series(X, N, ApproximateY),
    ExactY is exp(X),
    writeln(ApproximateY),
    writeln(ExactY).

Mistake photo
Photo with task
The input field for N and X should be displayed after start_exp. but an error is displayed that is in the attached photo. The task itself is to add rules to the program to determine the approximate value of the function using the series shown in the photo.

The input field for N and X should be displayed after start_exp. but an error is displayed that is in the attached photo. The task itself is to add rules to the program to determine the approximate value of the function using the series shown in the photo.

sum_series is not defined. Perhaps you want https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2

oooh i don't understand it

@Elerance-Anaiers - What you're calling functions, are actually predicates.

@Elerance-Anaiers - What question are you asking? Perhaps you should read [ask].

Applying the Logtalk linter to your code highlights several issues. Using SWI-Prolog as the Logtalk backend and assuming your code saved in a maths.pl file:
$ swilgt
...

?- {hook_objects(loader)}.
...
true.

?- logtalk_load(maths, [hook(object_wrapper_hook), source_data(on), tail_recursive(warning), portability(warning)]).
*     Unknown predicate called but not defined: fact_pow/3
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 11-14
*     
*     Unknown predicate called but not defined: factor/2
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 30-37
*     
*     Unknown predicate called but not defined: sum_series/3
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 41-49
*     
*     Call to non-standard Prolog built-in predicate: writeln/1
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 41-49
*     
*     Non-tail recursive predicate definition: factorial/2 
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 4-7
*     
*     Non-tail recursive predicate definition: pow/3 
*       while compiling object maths
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl between lines 19-23
*     
% [ /Users/pmoura/Downloads/maths.pl loaded ]
% 6 compilation warnings
true.

You will need at least to add definitions for all the missing predicates.
